# How do i show the div of another page after redirecting in Html?

Tags: html

I am Designing a small website in HTML. I have 2 pages index.html and about.html. In index.html i have the div which is named as services.

index.html

```
<div id="services" class="services">

         <p> Services </p>
        <div class="service-grid" style="padding:30px">
                    <div class="">
                        <span> </span>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/software.png" alt="" style=""/>
                    <h4>Enterprise Applications</h4>
                    <p>We know each and every nook and corner of the IT field. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In About.html i have link which is named as Services
About.html

```
<div class="header-right">
            <span class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=" "/></span>
                <ul class="nav1">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="act"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#services" >Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#work">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

My Problem is

When i am clicking the Services link in About.html page it is moving to the services div but it is not stable. On loading of the index.html page it s showing the services div for the first time after that it is moving to the top pf the page

Comment: Could you please explain in more details what do you mean by "After full loading of the page it is getting out of the Services div" ?

Comment: It should be working fine. Can you show us a live demo so that we can investigate?

Comment: NIsha, i've tried your snippet and it works fine. It is possible that there are some other factors, invoking this float-to-top situtation. You must have to create a fiddle and show your problem or provide full source code.

Comment: unless you post a whole index.html or at least most of it. It'll be hard to tell the reason since any css fragment may change the behaviour you think it should be.